# {Microsoft CRM 4.0} How to send e-mail to some users who has salesperson security role

Tags: dynamics-crm

I created a workflow . My workflow sends e-mails to users who has salesperson security role. But I have big problem. After I export and import customizations in different company users of old company are shown on the e-mail template. How can I create a worflow which sends e-mail to users who has selected security role.

Regards,
Erdogan Uslu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workflow editor isn't that powerful.  You can't select a bunch of users with certain attributes and apply an action to them.  You'll have to create a custom workflow activity.  Run as the admin user to retrieve the list of users with a certain role.  Base it off the SDk article [Retrieve the Roles for a User](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc151188.aspx)

You would need to reverse this expression, so to speak.  Add a condition expression on the role link, to match on the role name.  Then you would remove the condition expression from the system user link.  Make the role link a child of the system user link (right now the systemuser is a child of the role link).  Change qe.EntityName to "systemuser".

You'll then need to create an e-mail.  See SDK articles on sending e-mail and creating workflow activities.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Using a security role like that is quite a weak mechanism for grouping users. CRM has the concept of a Team. Can't you create a Team, then send your email to the team?