# How to check security role of a user in crm 4.0?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

How can I check user's role in workflow? I have a workflow it will send a mail to users if owner of created entity does not have sales manager role.

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is a continuation of:

[{Microsoft CRM 4.0} How to send e-mail to some users who has salesperson security role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103958/microsoft-crm-4-0-how-to-send-e-mail-to-some-users-who-has-salesperson-security)

What trouble are you having?
What have you tried?
Can you provide what code you've written for your workflow activity so far?